# Turn mechanism in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a turn mechanism in my app with this scenario: 
AppFrame gets list of users in system > It prompts message dialog "User's  turn! > User types his answers, clicks SubmitButton >  system adds to hashMap his answers > if there's no more users left it show frame with results, else it starts second user's turn with message dialog etc.

I tried to do something like that

```
public void turnMechanism() {
    for (final User user : gf.getUsers()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, user.getUserName()+'s turn);
        gameStopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                gameStopButtonActionPerformed(evt, user);

            }
        });
    }
    new ResultsFrame(gf);
    dispose();

}
private void userStop(User u){
    AnswerSet userSet = new AnswerSet(gameNameField.getText().trim()
            .toLowerCase(), gameAnimalField.getText().trim().toLowerCase(),
            gamePlantField.getText().trim().toLowerCase(), gameCountryField
                    .getText().trim().toLowerCase(), gameCityField
                    .getText().trim().toLowerCase(), gameOccupationField
                    .getText().trim().toLowerCase());
    answers.put(u, userSet);
}

private void gameStopButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt, User u) {
    userStop(u);
```

But it doesn't work properly. Can you give me a hint how to do that? Without static fields.

Comment: what doesn't work properly mean? what is the error you got or unexpected output?

Comment: There's no output in fact.

Comment: Is this Swing? What is "ResultFrame"? What is AnswerSet? Where would you have output?

Comment: Desired behavior: AppFrame gets list of users in system > It prompts message dialog "User's turn! > User types his answers, clicks SubmitButton > system adds to hashMap his answers > if there's no more users left it show frame with results, else it starts second user's turn with message dialog.

Comment: Please provide MCTaRE (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable … Example) to help you better.

Comment: What is the content of answers after all your users submit their answer?

Comment: AnswerSet works perfecly, ResutFrame shouldn't bother you too.

Comment: I suppose you have a frame with text fields to input name, animal, etc and a button `gameStop`. When you click this button it should prompt for next user and accepts his input and so on until all users are done. Is that the case?

Comment: Function turnMechanism() is used to initialize the application? Where do you call it from?

Comment: Yes. Really, I don't need you to give me code on a plate. I just want a hint or schema leading to solution. Sorry for all misunderstandings, This is my first question here. :(

Comment: I call it from contructor of GameFrame (frame with fields and stop Button)

Comment: Your problem is that you are initializing action on your single button for each user and all of them will execute when you press your button at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code on the plate that could work for you. 
Structure class for a user to store an answer:

```
public class Player {
    private final User user;
    private AnswerSet answer;

    public Player(User p_user) {
        user = p_user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setAnswer(AnswerSet answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public AnswerSet getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Here is class with the main logic for turn based behavior:

```
public class TurnBasedGame {
    public enum State {
        READY,
        RUNNING,
        ENDED
    }

    private final List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int rounds;
    private int currentRound;
    private int currentTurn;
    private State currentState = State.READY;


    public TurnBasedGame() {
        this(1);
    }

    public TurnBasedGame(int rounds) {
        this.rounds = rounds;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void start() {
        currentTurn = 0;
        currentRound = 0;
        currentState = State.RUNNING;
    }

    public void endPlayerTurn() {
        if (currentState != State.RUNNING) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Game is not started");
        }

        currentTurn++;

        if (currentTurn >= players.size()) {
            currentTurn = 0;
            currentRound = 0;
        }
        if (currentRound >= rounds) {
            currentState = State.ENDED;
        }
    }

    public State getCurrentState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
        return players.get(currentTurn);
    }
}
```

And here is how you weave it up with your code:

```
public void turnMechanism() {
    final TurnBasedGame game = new TurnBasedGame();

    for (final User user : gf.getUsers()) {
        game.addPlayer(new Player(user));
    }

    gameStopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            final Player currentPlayer = game.getCurrentPlayer();
            currentPlayer.setAnswer(createAnswerSet());
            game.endPlayerTurn();

            switch (game.getCurrentState()) {
                 case RUNNING:
                     //next player
                     showCurrentPlayerInfo(game);
                     break;
                 case ENDED:
                     //show your resutls here
                     showResults(game);
                     break;
            }
        }
    });
    game.start();
    showCurrentPlayerInfo(game);

    //not sure what this does
    new ResultsFrame(gf);
    dispose();
}

private void showCurrentPlayerInfo(TurnBasedGame p_game) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p_game.getCurrentPlayer().getUser().getUserName() + 's turn);
}

private void showResults(TurnBasedGame p_game) {
    for (Player player : p_game.getPlayers()) {
        final AnswerSet answer = player.getAnswer();
        //do whatever you want with the answer
    }
}
```